# str reset to 0 when not asked to?

Tags: python, shopping-cart

I am trying to print the total of the shopping list but every time i call on the string it prints 0 instead of what it should be.

```
cash_due = 0
import pickle
picklee = open('Store_stuff.pickle', 'rb')
contents = pickle.load(picklee)
picklee.close()


shopping_list = ['Name      price       quantity        total']

store_contents ='''Store Contents

Name        Price       GTIN-8 Code
Butter      £1.20       70925647
Chocolate   £1.00       11826975
Bread       £1.00       59217367
Cheese      £2.80       98512508
Bacon       £2.40       92647640
Lamb        £4.80       49811230
Ham         £2.59       53261496
Potatoes    £2.00       11356288
Chicken     £3.40       89847268
Eggs        £1.29       21271243'''

def item(barcode, quantity, cash_due, shopping_list):
    shopping_list.append(contents[barcode]['name']+'      £'+(str((int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))+'           '+str(quantity)+'            £'+str((int(quantity)*int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))
    print(cash_due)
    print(contents[barcode]['price'])
    print(quantity)
    cash_due += ((int(contents[barcode]['price'])*(int(quantity)))/100)
    print(cash_due)

def shopkeeper_ui():
    print('Welcome to Stanmore\'s Food Emporium! Feel free to browse.')
    print(store_contents)
    user_input = ''

    while user_input != 'finish':
        user_input = input('''Welcome to the checkout.
instructions -
if you are entering text make sure your \'CAP\'s Lock\' is turned off
if you are entering a barcode number, please enter it carefully
if you want to print your current recipt, enter \'recipt\'
if you want to see your current total, enter \'total\'
and if you are finished, enter \'finish\'

You can see the stores contents below
Thanks for shopping:  ''')

        if len(user_input) == 8:
            quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity that you want:  '))
            item(user_input, quantity, cash_due, shopping_list)
        elif user_input == 'recipt':
            count8 = 0
            for i in shopping_list:
                print(shopping_list[count8])
                count8 += 1
        elif user_input == 'finish':
            print('Your shopping list is',shopping_list,' \nand your total was', total,'\n Thank you for shopping with Stanmore\'s Food Emporium')
        elif user_input == 'total':
            print('your total is, £',cash_due)
        else:
            print('User_input not valid. Try again...')
shopkeeper_ui()
```

If i enter the code and my first entry is `21271243` (the barcode for eggs). then i enter 4 for the quantity. i can get the `shopping_list` `list` to understand the total and if I print the string cash_due from inside the item function it understands it but as soon as i try to call cash_due from the shopkeeper_ui function it prints 0 instead of what should be 5.12?

Comment: cash_due is not mutable. The change in item function is lost when leaving the function.

Comment: ok so do you know a way to make the change stay out of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cash_due is not mutable`. Changes in `item` function are lost when leaving the function.

Generally, the way out of this is to let the function (`item`) return the value.

In this case, I would just keep `cash_due` out of `item` function and let `item` only return the cost for that item. Something like this:

```
def item(barcode, quantity, shopping_list):
    shopping_list.append(contents[barcode]['name']+'      £'+(str((int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))+'           '+str(quantity)+'            £'+str((int(quantity)*int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))
    print(contents[barcode]['price'])
    print(quantity)
    cost = ((int(contents[barcode]['price'])*(int(quantity)))/100)
    print(cost)
    return cost

[...]

       if len(user_input) == 8:
            quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity that you want:  '))
            cash_due += item(user_input, quantity, shopping_list)
```

You don't have the same issue with shopping_list because it is a mutable: it is changed in place. Read about mutables to understand the concept.

However, it could be better design to not let item modify the list. It could just return both the list element and the cost, and the caller would modify the list.

```
def item(barcode, quantity):
    stuff = (contents[barcode]['name']+'      £'+(str((int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))+'           '+str(quantity)+'            £'+str((int(quantity)*int(contents[barcode]['price']))/100))
    cost = ((int(contents[barcode]['price'])*(int(quantity)))/100)
    return stuff, cost

[...]

       if len(user_input) == 8:
            quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity that you want:  '))
            stuff, cost = item(user_input, quantity, shopping_list)
            shopping_list.append(stuff)
            cash_due += cost
```